# LESS variable name for mixin with parameters

Tags: less

What I want:
a mixin with parameters named by a variable.

Without parameters it works like a charm:

```
@foo: test;

.@{foo} {
    length: 20px;
}

.bar {
  .test;
}
```

puts out:

```
.bar {
    length: 20px; 
}
```

Perfetct so far.
Now I want to do this:

```
@foo: test;

.@{foo}(@var) {
    length: @var;
}

.bar {
    .test(20px);
}
```

unfortunately outputs ..

> ParseError: Missing closing ')' on line 3, column 9:
>
> 2
>
> 3 .@{foo}(@var) {
>
> 4   length: @var;

I've already tried all crazy sorts of escaping. No luck so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know, parametric mixins cannot have such interpolated names. So I don't think whatever you are trying to do is possible.

Comment: Too bad.. Maybe it's part of the 3.0 release. I would love to have a mixin that writes mixins for me :D

Comment: "Maybe it's part of the 3.0 release" - no it won't - see the discussions after https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2702#issuecomment-144727038 and (more general) https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1399. *Typical XY-problem*. Not counting that for your particular example is not quite easy to see what your final goal is - like: "OK, I can customize the mixin name - so I change `@foo: test;` to `@foo: bar;` then what is supposed to happen with `.test(20px);`?